# Switching renderer off/on for an object in unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity, rendering

I have a GameObject called 'Stone' that is rendered on Game Play. I have attached a C# script called RenderOff to to make 'Stone' invisible on Game Play.

**RenderOff.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RenderOff : MonoBehaviour {


    void Start () {

        this.gameobject.renderer.enabled = false;

    }

}
```

It has errors - **Type 'RenderOff' does not contain a definition for `gameobject' and no extension method`gameobject' of type `RenderOff' could be found**.

What does that mean ?

Comment: C# is case sensitive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gameObject` is case-sensitive.

If you're using Unity 4.x, you should be able to disable a renderer like so:

```
this.gameObject.renderer.enabled = false;
```

If you're using Unity 5.x, the shortcut to `.renderer` has been removed. Instead, you'll need to call:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

Note too that you can also get away with not using `this.gameObject`, and just use `gameObject` instead:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```